# All even natural numbers with deficiency $2$ have digital root $1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to prove the following claim :

> Let $n$ be an even natural number such that $\sigma(n)=2n-2$ . All numbers $n$ with this property have [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) $1$ .

List of numbers with [deficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number) $2$ can be found at : https://oeis.org/A191363

Comment: Related: [All even numbers $n$ with $\sigma_1(n)=2n-8$ have digital root $4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175968/all-even-numbers-n-with-sigma-1n-2n-8-have-digital-root-4)

Comment: As a simple remark:  that list looks like the list of Fermat primes.  if $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ is prime then $\frac 12\times (F_n-1)\times F_n$ has deficiency $2$ (direct computation).  Easy to see that all these have the property you seek...perhaps that's the full list?

Comment: Since not everyone will know the name "digital root". A number $n$ has digital root $1$ if and only if $n\equiv 1\mod 9$. So , we have to show for even $n\ge 4$ : $\sigma(n)=2n-2\implies n\equiv 1\mod 9$. This is true for $4\le n\le 10^8$. Moreover, $3$ seems to be the only odd number $n$ with $\sigma(n)=2n-2$

Comment: You ought to have linked to your new question about deficiency 2, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180316/all-even-natural-numbers-with-deficiency-2-are-a-power-of-two-times-fermat-pri

Comment: I tried to prove that every even number with $\sigma(n)=2n-2$ has the form $2^k(2^{k+1}+1)$, where $2^{k+1}+1$ is a Fermat-prime. (See answer below). This would imply the conjecture , pointed out by lulu.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to prove this claim under [the following condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180316/15660)

> If $2^{2^k}+1$ is a prime number , then  $2^{2^k-1}\left(2^{2^k}+1\right)$ is a number with deficiency $2$ , and every even number with deficiency $2$ has this form .

*Proof*

Let $DR(n)$ denote digital root of $n$ . As Peter mentioned in his comment

$$ n \equiv DR(n) \pmod{9} \tag{1}$$

Next , for $k \ge 1$ we shall prove the following

$$ DR(2^{2^k}+1) =
\begin{cases}
5, & \text{if } 2^k=6t+2 \\
8, & \text{if }2^k=6t+4
\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

Since $2^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ and $2^{6t} \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ it follows that

$$2^{6t+2} \equiv 4 \pmod{9}~~ \text{and} ~~ 2^{6t+4} \equiv 7 \pmod{9} \tag{3}$$

Therefore ,

$$2^{6t+2}+1 \equiv 5 \pmod{9}~~ \text{and} ~~ 2^{6t+4}+1 \equiv 8 \pmod{9} \tag{4}$$

and (2) follows from (1) .

From (3) we have

$$2^{6t+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{9}~~ \text{and} ~~ 2^{6t+3} \equiv 8 \pmod{9} $$

Together with (4) this yields

$$2^{6t+1}\left(2^{6t+2}+1\right) \equiv 2\cdot 5 \pmod{9} \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$

and

$$2^{6t+3}\left(2^{6t+4}+1\right) \equiv 8\cdot 8 \pmod{9} \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$

Thus $DR(n)=DR(2^{2^k-1} \cdot F_k)=1$ ,where $F_k$ is a Fermat prime , follows from (1) .

Answer (score 0):

An approach imitating the proof of the form of every even perfect number ; Unfortunately, I did not manage to finish the proof.

Suppose , $n=2^k\cdot u$ with $k\ge 1$ and $u$ odd.

We have $$\sigma(n)=(2^{k+1}-1)\cdot \sigma(u)$$

and $$2n-2=2^{k+1}\cdot u-2$$

Hence $$(1)\ \ \ \ (2^{k+1}-1)\cdot \sigma(u)=2^{k+1}\cdot u-2$$

This implies $$\sigma(u)=\frac{(2^{k+1}-1)u+u-2}{2^{k+1}-1}=u+\frac{u-2}{2^{k+1}-1}$$

If $u$ is prime then we have $\sigma(u)=u+1$,hence we can conclude $$u-2=2^{k+1}-1$$ hence $$u=2^{k+1}+1$$ so $u$ is a Fermat prime and $n$ has the form to be proven.

$u=1$ can be ruled out because of $\sigma(u)=1$ which inserted in $(1)$ gives the contradiction $2^{k+1}-1=2^{k+1}-2$

What remains to show is that for composite $u$ we cannot have $$\frac{u-2}{\sigma(u)-u}=2^{k+1}-1$$

Unfortunately, I cannot prove this, but I wrote a small PARI/GP program verifying it for $u\le 10^8$ :

```
? forcomposite(u=1,10^8,if(Mod(u,2)==1,if(Mod(u-2,sigma(u)-u)==0,if(component(fa
ctor((u-2)/(sigma(u)-u)+1),1)~==2,print1(u," ")))))
?
```

So, for $u\le 10^8$ , all numbers with $n$ have the form to be proven.

I will continue the search. But perhaps, someone can finish the proof anyway.

Comment: I have extended the search to $u=10^9$ without finding a counter-example.

Comment: $\sigma (u)$ cannot be the multiple of 4, and it cannot be odd number either. Therefore $\sigma (u)$ is $4n+2$ form. That is, $u$ has something common with odd perfect number..

Comment: @didgogns:  Interesting!