# All even natural numbers with deficiency $2$ are a power of two times Fermat prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to prove following claim :

> If $2^{2^k}+1$ is a prime number , then  $2^{2^k-1}\left(2^{2^k}+1\right)$ is a number with deficiency $2$ , and every even number with deficiency $2$ has this form .

My attempt

Suppose first that $p=2^{2^k}+1$ is prime and set $n=2^{2^k-1}\left(2^{2^k}+1\right)$ . To show $n$ has deficiency $2$ we need only to show $\sigma(n)=2n-2$ . Since $\sigma$ is multiplicative and $\sigma(p)=p+1=2^{2^k}+2$ we know $\sigma(n)=\sigma(2^{2^k-1})\cdot \sigma(p)=\left(2^{2^k}-1\right)\left(2^{2^k}+2\right)= 2^{2^k} \cdot 2^{2^k}+2\cdot 2^{2^k}-2^{2^k}-2=2^{2^k}\cdot2^{2^k}+2^{2^k}-2 = 2^{2^k}\cdot\left(2^{2^k}+1\right)-2=2\cdot 2^{2^k-1} \cdot \left(2^{2^k}+1\right)-2 =2n-2 $

On the other hand , suppose $n$ is any even number with deficiency $2$ and write $n$ as $2^{t-1}m$ where $m$ is an odd integer and $t\ge2$ . Again $\sigma$ is multiplicative so $\sigma(2^{t-1}m)=\sigma(2^{t-1})\cdot  \sigma(m)=\left(2^{t}-1\right) \cdot\sigma(m)$ . Since $n$ has deficiency $2$ we also know that $\sigma(n)=2n-2=2^{t}m-2$ . Together these two criteria give $2^{t}m-2=\left(2^{t}-1\right) \cdot\sigma(m)$ , hence $2\cdot\left(2^{t-1}m-1\right)=\left(2^{t}-1\right) \cdot\sigma(m)$ . So $2^{t}-1 \mid 2^{t-1}m-1$

Now I am stuck . How do I proceed ?

**EDIT**

I want to apologize to Euclid and Euler because I took their proof structures without acknowledgements . God save my corrupted soul...

Comment: You should have linked to your recent question about numbers with deficiency 2, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177456/all-even-natural-numbers-with-deficiency-2-have-digital-root-1

Comment: You also probably shouldn't copy word-for-word [someone else's](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/EvenPerfect.html) proof structure :)

Comment: @ErickWong If there is a "math snippet" why not to use it ? :-)

Comment: @Pedja Because proofs are a lot like written essays,  not like source code (which you seem to be alluding to).  It's fine to learn from an experienced author's words, but be careful that it doesn't come at the expense of actually understanding the logic!  And I feel it's not polite to steal the template without some acknowledgment.

Comment: @ErickWong Shame on me :-)

Comment: Yes. All even numbers with deficiency 2 are a power of 2 times a Fermat prime & are in the form n(2n+1). 3 is conjectured to be the only odd number with this deficiency.